# Using the definite article with abstract nouns and some geographical names

Tags: definite-article, abstract-nouns

> Thousands of people watched the tidal bore of Qiantang River in China.
>
> phenomenon (something which happens in the nature)

[Source](https://www.newsinlevels.com/products/long-wave-in-china-level-2/)

I have noticed two mistakes in using the article (the name of the river used with the zero article and the word "nature" that does not require *the* in the sense it is used in the news story). The news team did not agree with me and gave me no feedback. Is there any foundation for using the article this way?

Comment: **the nature** is certainly not idiomatic there.  With rivers the article is almost always used when the name precedes "river" or when the name is used without the word "river". *The museum owns a painting of General Washington crossing the Delaware.*    *Maintenance of the bridge across the Delaware River is funded in part by tolls.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I agree that the article is definitely required when the name is mentioned without "river". But where the name follows "River", as it always does in Britain, you do also need the definite article. "There has been extensive flooding along the River Severn in recent winters".

Comment: @WS2:  I've seen and heard constructions like **on River Severn** and that's why I said "almost always" rather than "always". Samuel Johnson in his dictionary uses it without the article, and there are more modern attestations as well.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'll not argue with Samuel Johnson, but as a native UK speaker any modern absence of the article, in this sense, sounds odd to me.

Comment: The problem is that in the exercises attached to the news story the word "nature" is used with the zero article: "...something which happens in nature". How should it be explained to students? Perhaps, I'm too concerned about other people's slips :)

Comment: @Yulia Idiomatically, "nature" does not take an article when used in this sense. One would however speak of "a kind nature" or "the nature of the problem". The point, I think, is that nature can be both a "count" and a "non-count" noun. So when it is being used as a non-count noun, it does not take an article.

Comment: @WS2: Yes, I agree, but this specific case is about using " nature" with the zero article.

Comment: @Yulia What exactly do you mean by "the zero article"? I took it to mean "no article at all".

Comment: @WS2: We mean the same thing http://www.grammaring.com/the-zero-article

Comment: @Yulia, the Level 3 version of the article uses much more natural-sounding English.  I expect for Level 2 they greatly simplify, and occasionally make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary definition 1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nature), **nature** is a mass noun, otherwise known as uncountable. Under some circumstances, you can use a definite article with a mass noun: here is a good explanation of when **not** to do this:

> If we want to refer to something general and the nouns that we are using are either plural or uncountable, we leave out articles. [Definite and indefinite articles in English Grammar](https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/definite-and-indefinite-articles/)

No article is required for **nature** in your quote.

When you talk about a river, ocean or sea and you use either the name on its own or the name and designation, you normally use **the** in front of it. Strangely, this doesn't apply to lakes, ponds, brooks and streams.

The estimable Tᴚoɯɐuo may quote references saying that you can talk about the river Severn without a definite article, but I lived near the Severn for the first 20 years of my life, and I never heard anybody omit the definite artice.

I therefore think that you have a very strong case for saying that **Qiantang River** deserves a definite article.

You say "the Level 3 version of the article uses much more natural-sounding English". Level 3 probably uses news reports verbatim or with few changes. The  Level 2  version will require rewriting rather than minor changes. The company that produces this web site is based in the Czech Republic and, while their efforts are commendable, it is clear that they are not native English speakers.

Comment: I am not sure that I'll be using this website again (though I like the idea of news stories written for different levels).

Comment: Yes, it is a nice idea. I used to use newspaper articles: I asked students to read them and then write a summary in exactly a hundred words. It is useful because the students don't have to be creative, but they do have to try out various ways of saying the same thing.